# Datepicker between two ages 21 and 25 wpf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, datepicker

I have made an application where the user selects there date of birth using a `DatePicker`. The user must be over 21 and under 26. If the user is over 21 and under 26 then a message box appears saying "Success". However when I select a date of birth that is between 21 and 25 nothing happens. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I think it is minusing 21 and 26 from my selected date in my `datePicker`

My Code is as fallows

xaml

```
<DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="dpkDOB" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="10" />
```

xaml.cs

```
  DatePicker dp = new DatePicker();

            DateTime dateMinimum = dpkDOB.SelectedDate.Value.AddYears(-21);
            DateTime dateMaximum = dpkDOB.SelectedDate.Value.AddYears(-26); // 26, as this would include somebody whose just below 26 years old
            DateTime birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dp.SelectedDate);

            if (birthDate > dateMinimum && birthDate < dateMaximum)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Success");
            }
```

Comment: what happens when you trace it through?

Comment: i dont know wpf but in any platform datepickers is something you want a plugin for

Comment: If I select D.O.B as 30/05/1994 for example the `dateMinimum` shows 30/05/1973 and the `dateMaximum` shows 30/05/1968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You picked the wrong `DatePicker` for comparison:

```
DateTime birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dp.SelectedDate);
```

should be

```
DateTime birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dpkDOB.SelectedDate);
```

**According the comments:**

```
DateTime birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dpkDOB.SelectedDate);

if(birthDate > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-26) && birthDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-21))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

**If you need this more often in your solution, think about an extension like this:**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TimeSpan Age(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return (DateTime.Now - dt);
    }

    public static int Years(this TimeSpan ts)
    {
        return (int)((double)ts.Days / 365.2425);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
DateTime birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dpkDOB.SelectedDate);

if (birthDate.Age().Years() > 21 && birthDate.Age().Years() < 26)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I added that bit of code in and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your goal is to define an age-rang according the current day right?

Comment: Yes the user needs to be over 21 and less than 26 from todays date. I also tried using this `dateMinimum = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-21);` but I was getting an error on "Now"

Comment: I've shortened this a bit.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks for your time and help :)